# What possibilities exist to turn into beasts, while maintaining personality and mental abilities?

Tags: dnd-5e

What opportunities exist in D&D 5e in order to turn into beasts, while maintaining personality and mental abilities (Intelligence, Wisdom and not necessary Charisma)?

As far as I can see, one of the obvious solutions is [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#WildShape). Are there any other options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes, other options do exist.

### Options that keep mental scores

Wild Shape allows you to retain your mental ability scores, as you mentioned.

Additionally, [shapechange](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange), a 9th level druid or wizard spell, works (though it only affects you). To affect others, you could use the 8th level druid spell [animal shapes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animal-shapes).

### Options that don’t work

[Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) explicitly calls out that the mental ability scores are changed to match the new form, as does [true polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) and [mass polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-polymorph).